# How to install Jira Subversion plugin and upload source code

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

it's my first use of my Jira account, and i created a project, and i want to upload source code to a my hosted source control, so i go to plugins and i found only CVS modules why ?

can any one please tell me how to install SVN on my Jira account, and upload my project ?

I am using Hosted solution (source code will be hosted on Jira).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about JIRA Studio (or OnDemand as they now call it).

Atlassian's hosted solutions are probably not going to make the SVN plugin available ot you because they have a commercial product (FishEye) for that.

The subversion plugin can only be installed manually by dropping the proper jars and class files onthe right places on the server. I doubt they are going to do that for you in a hosted environment. You will probably need to purchase/rent and use FishEye if you want integration with version control.